# Can you autoscroll text on the Echo Show?

Tags: echo, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

I'm updating an Alexa skill to work on the new Echo Show.  In one area of the skill, I've got large block of text that is took long for one screen.  Is there a way to get Alexa/the Show to autoscroll the text as Alexa is saying it?  The example I'm trying to follow with this thought is how Alexa shows and scrolls song lyrics when it plays music.

Comment: Hi.. Have you find the solution for this?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?